# How can I find kedro_cli.py in my project?

Tags: python, shell, kedro

I installed Kedro using *pip install*, and I made a new project using `kedro new`. I was able to run (`kedro run --pipeline myPipelineName`) from terminal in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) or from cmd when I make cd to the project. But I need to run it from my PHP file using `shell_exec()`. I need `kedro_cli.py`, but I can't find it.

I tried running

```
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\webmap\\python\\detect\\venv\\Scripts\\python.py C:\xampp\htdocs\webmap\python\detect\src\detect\__main__.py run --pipeline objects-prediction
```

And it is not working. I once tried using *kedro_cli*, but this time I can't seem to find it in the project.

Comment: Please provide reference to the documentation of kedro that shows this form of invocation specifically and [edit] that into your question. And have you raised a support ticket with the software vendor already and informed about your usability issue with the software?

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: What does `python -m kedro info` give? Have you tried venv/bin/kedro? Documentation is here: https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/development/commands_reference.html#invoke-kedro-cli-from-python-optional

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and then later accept it. this is important so that the question is marked as answered (and it is totally valid that you answer your own questions)

Comment: "Tried running" - when you try this, concretely what do you see? What do you think you should see instead, and why? How is that different?

Comment: Why double backslashes for the path to `python.py`, but single backslashes for `__main__.py`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was so simple. I used
`path_to_venv\\venv\\Scripts\\kedro run --pipeline my-pipeline-name`

I was new to this, so I didn't know that a script could be used in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is packaged, you can use `python -m <module>` to run it as CLI.

Comment: it was solved using the following script Scripts\\kedro  in the venv folder. thank u!